# Convert strings to MongoId in array of objects

Tags: mongodb

We have a collection which stores a list of sub objects:

```
{
    _id: MongoID,
    title: 'Some title',
    items: [
       {
          sub_type: 'MongoId'
       }
    ]
}
```

Annoyingly it turns out we've been storing the `item.sub_type` as both MongoId Objects and as strings.

I've created a query to find all the string versions: (I'm using a regex as some old items were just numbers instead of Ids, they can be ignored).

```
$query = array(
  'items' => array(
    '$elemMatch' => array(
      'sub_type' => array(
        '$type' => 2,
        '$regex' => new MongoRegex('/^[a-f\d]{24}$/i')
      )
    )
  )
);
$results = $mongo->collection->find( $query );
```

I'm now trying to come up with the best way to convert these to MongoIds. I can easily loop through them in PHP and update them, but this seems like a waste.
Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: When you say string you mean a string representation of a mongo id ? Could you provide an example of one of those IDs?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean.
This is an example of an Id, 569376eb235b6597268b4574

Answer (score 0):

I just realised I didn't really understand the question. Here goes an update. This one should do it.

Using mongo console...

```
 db.collection.find({}).forEach(function (x) {
     x.items.forEach(function (y) {
         y.sub_type = ObjectId(y.sub_type);
     });
     db.collection.save(x);
 });
```